# How can you set the horizontal axis interval in a WPF Toolkit Chart Control?

Tags: wpf, charts, wpftoolkit

I'm using the chart control from the WPF Toolkit. How can I set the interval of the X axis?

I have the following XAML code:

```
<Grid Height="800">

        <chartingToolkit:Chart  Name="lineChart" Title="Pressure over Time" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="20,50,20,0" Height="500">

            <chartingToolkit:Chart.Axes>
                <chartingToolkit:LinearAxis Title="Pressure" Orientation="Y" Interval="100" />
                <chartingToolkit:LinearAxis Title="Time" Orientation="X" Interval="100" />
            </chartingToolkit:Chart.Axes>

            <chartingToolkit:LineSeries DependentValuePath="Value" IndependentValuePath="Key" ItemsSource="{Binding}"  Name="Test"
                                        IsSelectionEnabled="True" ClipToBounds="False">
            </chartingToolkit:LineSeries>


        </chartingToolkit:Chart>

        <Button Width="100" Height="24" Margin="20,556,1058,220" Content="More" Name="Button1" />

    </Grid>
```

The Y Axis works fine, it shows the interval of 100 but the X axis puts itself on the top (please see the added image) and the interval is the exact amounts of points. Why doesnt it listen to the Interval="100" property in the xaml? And why doesn't it place itself on the bottom?

[image: Chart sample]

Answer (score 1):

For the location of the linearAxis, you can set the `Location` property to `"Bottom"`

in code:

```
<chartingToolkit:LinearAxis Title="Time" Orientation="X" Interval="100" 
Location="Bottom" />
```

For the interval problem, i don't know...

Comment: Your comment gave me more insight into the problem. If I set the Location of the X axis to "Top", the label "Time" shows at the top and the actual values switch to the bottom. It seems that the axes of the chartingToolkit:LineSeries don't listen at all to the properties set in <chartingToolkit:Chart.Axes>.

Comment: I know, I usually just use the default axis, but the default one shows all the values on the axis instead of a normal interval one, like your problem. This is an issue I would also like to see resolved myself.

Comment: Any results of resolving this issue? I have exactly the same problem.